# No Applets work in Chrome or FF with java 1.7.0.40

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, applet, classnotfoundexception

I have done some testing and no applets seem to work in Chrome or Firefox under java 1.7.0.40.  Funnily enough, those applets do work in IE (all versions).

When I uninstall 1.7.0.40 and revert back to java 1.6.0.30 the applets work again in all browsers.

I have been using the following link to test if the applets are working

https://java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp

NOTE: If you have an old version of java, ignore the prompt to download the latest version and click the link below to test anyway.

EDIT: Currently using Windows 7 and latest version of each browser.

EDIT 2: I would add a screenshot but I'm not allowed due to being a noob.   The error I get is ClassNotFoundException [When clicking on the test link above.]

Comment: Currently using Windows 7 and latest version of each browser.

Comment: How are you deploying applets on your sites. Post some code and I'll try to help you. I had similar problem and now it's solved.

Comment: I have Win7 with java 7u40 and the latest Firefox and Chrome. Despite some nasty security warnings/boxes from both browsers everything is working. So must be something wrong with your system/configuration

Comment: TomaszDz, in the OP there is a link to the Applet I was testing with.

Comment: Thank you Lonzak.  Everyone on my floor at work has the same problem.  I'll test on some pc's on different networks etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network and SOE is managed by a third party.  After the latest round of updates from them applets are working again in all browsers with the latest version of java.

Comment: Standard Operating Environment

Answer (score 0):

From [java downloads page](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp):

> If you use 32-bit and 64-bit browsers interchangeably, you will need
>   to install both 32-bit and 64-bit Java in order to have the Java
>   plug-in for both browsers.

I'd suspect this is going on. Could you try to install both 32-bit and 64-bit versions, if you have mixed browsers.

There's more information in here: http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml

Comment: We are stuck on 32 bit Win 7, so unfortunately that is not the cause in our situation.

Comment: @Aaron ok. Could you add some more details to the question: what is the actual exception message, including missing class, that you get? Did you first uninstall all previous versions before installing java 7? what is your firefox version?